# Factory-pattern for Selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, factory-pattern

Currently I am trying to write an automated test suite using Selenium and Proboscis. I am trying to abstract the webdriver and implementing through the factory pattern. `Page_object` class is also created here, which takes the webdriver as an argument while creating an object. Below is the code.

```
     import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
     from proboscis import TestProgram
     from proboscis import test
     from proboscis import before_class
     from proboscis import after_class    

     class WebdriverFactory:
        @staticmethod
        def getWebdriver(browserName):  
            if(browserName == 'firefox'):
             return webdriver.Firefox()
            elif(browserName == 'chrome'):
             return webdriver.Chrome()
            elif(browserName == 'ie'):
             return webdriver.Ie()        

            raise Exception("No such " + browserName + " browser exists")  

   class Page_Object:
    def __init__(self, driver):
      self.driver = driver

    def go_to_home(self):
        self.driver.get("http://google.com")
        return self
    def go_to_page(self,url):
        self.driver.get(url)
        return self
    def run_search(self, url, query):
        self.driver.get(url)
        self.driver.find_element_by_id(locators['search_box']).send_keys(query)
        self.driver.find_element_by_id(locators['search_button']).click()

    def tear_down(self):
        self.driver.close()   

   @test(groups=['selenium'])
   class Test_Scripts:

     @test(groups=['WebDemo'])
     def test_1(self):
        driver = WebdriverFactory.getWebdriver("firefox")
        pageObj = Page_Object(driver)
        pageObj.run_search("http://google.com",'apples')
        pageObj.tear_down()      
     def run_tests(self):
        TestProgram().run_and_exit()

   Test_Scripts().run_tests()
```

Is this  the right way of doing this? Or are there any better solutions possible? 
If you find something stupid then please point out and ignore my negligence since I am new to Python and Selenium.

Comment: Really surprised that this question hasn't got much attention :(

Answer (score 4):

You are implementing page object correctly, in that you are doing it the way most people do.

I have done page objects a little differently - not requiring a webdriver to instantiate them. Because I often run into several pages with different body contents, but identical header and footer sections. So rather than duplicating header/footer locators and methods in each page object, I have a separate page obj just for header, and just for footer. But then using 1 webdriver to instantiate multiple page objects to test a single page, seemed to violate the paradigm. So my page objects are really just a collection of locators and methods, and not necessarily a webdriver.

I realize you didn't mention headers or footers... I guess the reason why most people build their page objects around a webdriver is to create a paradigm which assumes only 1 page object per page. In my case, that would have resulted in duplicate code across page objects. Something to consider. Hope that helps!

Comment: Pat Meeker, do you have some example to share which I am exactly looking for? By the way, currently using [this](https://github.com/ncbi/robotframework-pageobjects) as starting point, combined with `robot framework`. As you mentioned, there are common objects and not like to repeat on each page. Also not much hands on python for getting `inheretence` to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

There is Python library which provides page factory approach to implement page object model in selenium -

[selenium-page-factory](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-page-factory/)